# Why won't can't I read from my usocket using usocket::socket-receive?

Tags: sockets, lisp, common-lisp

I'm learning common-lisp, and I'm trying to write a dumb chat program using a client and server tcp socket connection using the [usocket library](https://common-lisp.net/project/usocket/api-docs.shtml). Below is my function.

```
(defun receive-thread (socket)
  (block receiver-nested-loop
         (loop 
           (let ((ready-socket (usocket::wait-for-input socket)))
             (let ((return-buffer (usocket::socket-receive ready-socket nil nil))) 
                 (if (not (eq return-buffer :eof))
                     (handle-received-data return-buffer)
                     (return-from receiver-nested-loop)))))))
```

I'm doing simple test runs in 2 terminals, I am calling the (main) function manually (I know how to compile and script this).

In the first (replace x's with my ip address): sbcl --load chat.lisp -a xxx.xx.xxx.xx -s

In the second: sbcl --load chat.lisp -a xxx.xx.xxx.xx

When my program gets to the above function I get the following error:

```
debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD RUNNING {10069DF743}>:
  There is no applicable method for the generic function
    #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION USOCKET:SOCKET-RECEIVE (1)>
  when called with arguments
    (#<USOCKET:STREAM-SERVER-USOCKET {10069DF673}> NIL NIL).
```

Here is the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KRNzGfPx) for my complete code.

Can someone help me figure out what I've done wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

EDIT: Removed extra ':'s in the program and retested. The behavior and error remains the same. All the function calls are exported symbols, I just did it out of c++ instincts.

Comment: The fact that you're using `::` to call the functions suggests that you're calling internal functions of the package. The public interface should be in exported symbols, which you can access with `:` instead of `::`.

Comment: Nah, I'm just new and dumb. I automagically coded it like c++ instead of a lisp exported symbol. I just modifed all "::" to be single ":" and it's the same error

Comment: Yeah, just checked the docs...

Comment: You can't call `socket-receive` on a listening socket, only on a connected socket. You need to call `socket-accept` to get the new connection. This is just like C or C++ -- you call `accept()` on the listening socket, and `recv()` on the connected socket that it returns.

Comment: Yuuuuup. At some point I'll come back here with the working code and answer my own question I think

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted hints that you're using `usocket:socket-receive` incorrectly (slightly cleaned up):

```
There is no applicable method for the generic function
USOCKET:SOCKET-RECEIVE
when called with arguments
USOCKET:STREAM-SERVER-USOCKET
```

[Documentation for this function](https://common-lisp.net/project/usocket/api-docs.shtml#socket-receive) says that `usocket:socket-receive` will "receive data from a datagram socket". I suspect the socket you're trying to read is TCP socket and not a UDP socket.